# Why php class is not found which belongs to other directory?

Tags: phpunit

My `SampleTest.php` is under unit directory which belongs to tests directory and my model class `User.php` in **Models** directory which belongs to **App** directory.

When i run the script, it shows error and says:

> class App\Models\User not found

The namespace in `User.php` is: `App\Models` and the class declaration in `SampleTest.php` is:

```
$user= new \App\Models\User;
```

Comment: Have you configured any autoloading? PHP does not magically find other files on its own. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php Without autoloading, you have to `require` the source file(s) you need.